# I want main class event to be raised in supported form

Tags: vb.net, class, events

I have public class, with event declared in it.

And have procedure which shows modal form.

The form has buttons, on whichs click I want the main event to be raised. How to achieve this?

for example:

```
Public class MyClass

Public Event MyEvent(arg as date)

Public Sub ShowForm()

using frm as new frmMyForm
frm.showDialog()
End Using

....
End Class
```

On forms button click event

```
RaiseEvent MyClass.MyEvent(Today)
```

I have passed egzemplar of class as property, but nothing helped.

Comment: Your thing is sort of inside out.  You have a class that shows a form, but you want the form to raise an event on behalf of the class?  First the form needs a reference to the class, then add a method for the form to tell the class something happened.  The class can then RaiseEvent

Comment: @Plutonix  form is in the same project as the class, therefore I thing no need to make reference. I don't know how to make reference to class from form. I never did it before. I'm passing class egzemplar as property and using its methods.

Comment: We can only go by the code given - there is nothing there for a `egzemplar`.  In the code shown, the form object - `frmMyForm` - has no knowledge of the class that created and showed it

Comment: @Plutonix you helped me. I have really created method in the main class with date parameter. In button click I'm calling above method of passed egzemplar with desired argument. and then raising event in class. it works fine now. thanks, write your comment as answer, and I'll check it as usefull

Comment: Question is closed

Comment: Go ahead and add your own answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem. I have really created method in the main class with date parameter. In button click I'm calling above method of passed egzemplar with desired argument. and then raising event in a class. it works fine now.

In my situation code is more harder, therefore I provide only a simple example instead.

```
Public class MyClass

Public Event MyEvent(arg as date)

Public sub FromOtherPlanet(dt as Date)
RaiseEvent MyEvent(dt)
End sub


Public Sub ShowForm()
  using frm as new frmMyForm
  frm.Egz = Me
  frm.showDialog()
  End Using
End Sub
....
End Class
```

in the form

```
  Public class MyForm 

  dim Temp_Egz as MyClass 

  public property Egz as Myclass
  Get 
  .......
  Set
  ....
  End Property 


  private sub button1_click.....
  egz.FromOtherPlanet(today)
  end sub 

  end class
```

Comment: It's probably better to just pass the class through the Constructor: `Public Sub New(egz As Myclass)` in your MyForm class.